# How to replace PyV8, because PyV8 no longer update

Tags: javascript, python-3.6, pyv8

i use python 3.6,there is no PyV8 release edition fitting the python 3.6. In my python program I want to read the data which is in js code.  How will I do？
[image: pycharm里显示 version is highre than latest, I dont know why]

Comment: nobody use PyV8 in python 3.6?

Comment: this all depends on how you currently use pyv8, for example is integrating with nodejs (which uses V8) an option?

Answer (score 0):

[STPyV8](https://github.com/cloudflare/stpyv8)

It’s the successor to PyV8, owned by Cloudflare.